# Difference between remove_field in drop filter plugin and remove_field in mutate filter plugin

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration, dplyr

I am wondering whats the difference between this

```
filter {
  drop {
    remove_field => ["some_field"]
  }
}
```

and this

```
filter {
  mutate {
    remove_field => ["some_field"]
  }
}
```

reading the documentation, it seems to say the same thing?

drop filter: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-drop.html#plugins-filters-drop-remove_field .

mutate filter: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-remove_field

I notice that if I replace mutate with drop in my config, my entire event just drops, and the remove_field option doesnt seem to do anything additional... what am i missing here?

Answer (score 1):

The drop filter stops processing the event and won't send it to your outputs.  That seems to be what you're seeing when you use it.

The mutate filter allows you to perform certain modifications to the event, including removing individual fields as you've seen.

Two different filters for two different use cases.

Also the `remove_field` option is always available in any filter plugin, as part of the common options. It explains why the option is present in the drop filter, even if it doesn't make a lot of sense to have it here.